# Send node to front tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

Like the neanderthal I am, I chose to make the following graph in tikz as such:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=blue] (-1,0) circle (3pt);
\draw[fill=blue] (-1,0.5) circle (3pt);
\draw[fill=blue] (-1,1) circle (3pt);
\draw[fill=blue] (-1,1.5) circle (3pt);
\draw[fill=blue] (-1,2) circle (3pt);
\draw[fill=red] (1,0.25) circle (3pt);
\draw[fill=red] (1,0.75) circle (3pt);
\draw[fill=red] (1,1.25) circle (3pt);
\draw[fill=red] (1,1.75) circle (3pt);
\draw[thin] (-1,0) -- (1,0.25) -- (-1,0.5) -- (1,0.75) -- (-1, 1) -- (1,1.25) -- (-1, 1.5) -- (1, 1.75) -- (-1,2) -- (1,1.25) -- (-1,0.5) -- (1,1.75) -- (-1,1) -- (1,0.25) -- (-1,2) -- (1,0.75) -- (-1,0) -- (1, 1.75);
\draw[thin] (-1,0) -- (1,1.25);
\draw[thin] (-1,1.5) -- (1,0.25);
\draw[thin] (-1,1.5) -- (1,0.75);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, this gives me the minor, but fairly annoying issue that the lines lie on top of the nodes and the graph doesn't look nearly as good as it could. Is there a simple way to bring the nodes to the front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to change the order of the commands in the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thin] (-1,0) -- (1,0.25) -- (-1,0.5) -- (1,0.75) -- (-1, 1) -- (1,1.25) -- (-1, 1.5) -- (1, 1.75) -- (-1,2) -- (1,1.25) -- (-1,0.5) -- (1,1.75) -- (-1,1) -- (1,0.25) -- (-1,2) -- (1,0.75) -- (-1,0) -- (1, 1.75);
\draw[thin] (-1,0) -- (1,1.25);
\draw[thin] (-1,1.5) -- (1,0.25);
\draw[thin] (-1,1.5) -- (1,0.75);
\draw[fill=blue] (-1,0) circle (3pt);
\draw[fill=blue] (-1,0.5) circle (3pt);
\draw[fill=blue] (-1,1) circle (3pt);
\draw[fill=blue] (-1,1.5) circle (3pt);
\draw[fill=blue] (-1,2) circle (3pt);
\draw[fill=red] (1,0.25) circle (3pt);
\draw[fill=red] (1,0.75) circle (3pt);
\draw[fill=red] (1,1.25) circle (3pt);
\draw[fill=red] (1,1.75) circle (3pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah so it overlays the latest commands on top. That makes sense, thanks.